# getting data after building widgets

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get data from Database, but my widget is built before I can get them...

```
class CategoriesWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CategoriesWidgetState createState() => _CategoriesWidgetState();
}

class _CategoriesWidgetState extends State<CategoriesWidget> {
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  String token;
  var _isInit = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    if (!_isInit) {
      super.initState();
      fetchCat();
      _isInit = true;
    }
  }

  var categories = {};
  fetchCat() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      token = prefs.getString('api_token');
    });
    await fetchCategories(token).then((result) {
      categories = result[1];
      print(categories);
      print(result[1]);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    print('2');
    return Column(
     // code here
    );
  }
}
```

you can see that I print 1 and 2 to see which one is getting the first and I got as result 2 then 1.

Comment: You can show loader until data get or use futurebuilder

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede how should i use it?

Comment: You want to fetch data first and then show UI right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `FutureBuilder`.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: _fetchCat(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
        ? MyWidget(data: snapshot.data)
        : Text('Loading...'),
  );
}
```

And with a FutureBuilder, your Widget could probably stay Stateless.

Here is a Minimal Working Example:

[image]

### Full source code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'StackOverflow Answer',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: CategoriesWidget()),
    );
  }
}

class CategoriesWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CategoriesWidgetState createState() => _CategoriesWidgetState();
}

class _CategoriesWidgetState extends State<CategoriesWidget> {
  Future<String> _fetchCat() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    return 'Category';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: _fetchCat(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) => Text(
          snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data ?? 'NO CATEGORY' : 'Loading...'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i am sorry for asking that but i didnt understand how should i use this with a widget.. :3

Comment: `Text` is a Widget.  I updated the first code snippet with a `MyWidget`. Is it more clear?

Comment: The method 'MyWidget' isn't defined for the type '_CategoriesWidgetState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'MyWidget'.
 it gave me this

Comment: i used set state so i can build it when an index is equal to 1 my widget come to live and when its different it show me circularprogress

Comment: What is [my widget]? I suppose this is what should replace MyWidget. What [index] are you talking about?